# Code Coverage on React with Puppeteer + Istanbul

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, puppeteer, istanbul

I have an app created with `create-react-app` and some UI tests written in Jest + Istanbul.

I want to get code coverage of these UI tests. I like to keep using jest as I already use it for unit-tests.

I'd like not to eject `create-react-app` if at all possible. But I'm open to it if there is no other choice.

**What I've tried so far:**

in `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
  "uitest": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom --verbose --testMatch='**/*.ui-test.{js}'",
}
```

if I run `npm run uitest -- --coverage`

[image: attempt 1 failure]

^ I think in above scenario it only captures the tests and not the actual App.

**How do I fix this?**

---

Other failed attempts:

1) [How to cover React jsx files in Istanbul?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866194/how-to-cover-react-jsx-files-in-istanbul) - Don't apply as I'm using `create-react-app`

2) https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3257 - apparently this feature was suggested but was rejected.

3) https://github.com/istanbuljs/puppeteer-to-istanbul/issues/18 - There is a library called puppeteer-to-istanbul but it doesn't support source maps. (See the link for issue)

4) I also looked at the book *Node.js Web Development - Fourth Edition* on safaribooks - I found a useful guide for Puppeteer but it doesn't seem to cover, code coverage.

5) Book *Hands-On Continuous Integration and Delivery* on safaribooks - has a section on Puppeteer + Jest testing, doesn't say anything about code coverage.

6) I tried `puppeteer-to-istanbul` -> We can calculate code coverage for bundle this way, it doesn't support source-maps.

7) Attempted Enselic's suggestion but couldn't get it working. It seems to crash on `push` method inside custom preset when trying to push `babel-plugin-istanbul`.

Comment: Hi, I'm the guy who filed https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3257.
FYI I ended up doing a "partial eject" i.e. only ejecting build.js and dependencies (see https://github.com/Enselic/sequencediagram.io/commit/6eb3873b4f1e3c06aa433602df8821f7914eb47c) Then you can add your own preset that adds code coverage (see https://github.com/Enselic/sequencediagram.io/blob/master/config/babel-preset-sequencediagram-io.js) while still keeping the goodies of other react-scripts
parts without bloating your repositoriy.

Comment: @Enselic OK Thanks, I'll try this approach. Just curios what did you do to partially eject, copy new things, and use git to revert, copy necessary stuff back?. BTW that is some good piece of software as well (starred).

Comment: Yes exactly: to partially eject, I did a full, normal eject, then manually undid what I did not want to eject. Glad to hear you liked my project, and thanks for the star :)

Comment: In the end I decided to focus on writing more unit tests. I also attempted @Enselic's suggestion, but I couldn't get it working. :)  I'll keep the question and see if someone has some more ideas. Once bounty is allowed, I shall also try that.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you missing [collectCoverageFrom](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html#collectcoveragefrom-glob) option in your `package.json` file.

Try to insert into your `package.json` something like:

```
  "jest": {
    ...
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx}",
      "!**/setupTests.js",
      "!**/**/*.test.js"
    ],
```

Also it's a good idea to skip coverage for test files, as it spoils the overall coverage. For this case use `!` in `collectCoverageFrom` array as show in the example ;)

Comment: `collectCoverageFrom` is not the issue here. I already have it defined and it is working fine for unit tests. This is not for unit tests but for UI tests, so I need to get coverage from what is running in the browser.

Comment: Ok I see, did you try to use official documentation approach? https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#class-coverage

Comment: That doesn't work as create-react-app uses webpack to transpile(js 2 js compile) the js files. I already tried it. It creates coverage for the bundle of js which is not useful.

Comment: there was discussion on github which might help you https://github.com/istanbuljs/puppeteer-to-istanbul/issues/18#issuecomment-418182808

Comment: it has example implementation of transfering puppeter coverage from browser https://github.com/smokku/wrte/blob/62059a4/test/runner.js#L36

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions. I've already gone in that path. But either way there doesn't seem to be possible without ejecting `create-react-app`. If I eject it I loose it's advantages.